# How to know if thread is finished in Lazarus

Tags: multithreading, lazarus

I'm new on threads so this is my question:

How can I check if the thread is over.

Escenario:

My app starts, then when I click on a button, the thread starts, and in the same click event I want to check if the thread is finished so I can call a new window that depends on the info that the thread throws.

```
MyThread:=TMyThread.Create(True);

        if Assigned(MyThread.FatalException) then begin
           raise MyThread.FatalException;
        end;

        MyThread.Start; 

        //check if it's done
        //How can I check if the Thread is finished so I can call the form
        frmUpdateLog.ShowModal;
```

When I do it as the code below the message window shows but there is no info, cause the thread is still running.

Comment: Don't check - signal the GUI thread when done. Send/Post a message and Show your form from the message-handler, (or use some other 'Lazarussy' inter-thread comms mechanism).

Comment: I added a boolean property to the Thread, when the thread is finished I set the property to True and while is running I check it on a repeat loop: 

repeat
AllFinished = True;
if not MyThread.AFinished then AllFinished = False;
until AllFinished = True;

Comment: See also TThread.Waitfor http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tthread.waitfor.html